# How to edit the value in a list of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
EVENT = {
    'summary': 'Dinner with friends',
    'start':  {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T19:00:00'},
    'end':    {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T22:00:00'},
}
```

I have this dictionary. I would like the manipulate or edit the value of date time in the start list. How would i access it and change the value?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: EVENT["start"]['dateTime'] = NewVal

Comment: Oh i tried this but looking at it i wrote it the wrong way. Thank you Very much. How dumb of me haha.  @Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EVENT = {
    'summary': 'Dinner with friends',
    'start':  {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T19:00:00'},
    'end':    {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T22:00:00'},
}
print(EVENT["start"]['dateTime'])
EVENT["start"]['dateTime'] = "New Value"   
print(EVENT["start"]['dateTime'])
```

**Output:**

```
2015-09-15T19:00:00
New Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example if you want to modify the date-time of the start of the event:

```
event['start']['dateTime'] = your_new_date
```

*Note: please use capitalized words only for constants*